# How to make an interface property conditional based on a string value

Tags: typescript

I have a function called `getBooksPayload` which returns an object with 3 properties in it. A couple of object properties are conditional based on a property `areBooksThereInLibrary` value.

```
interface BooksList {
  areBooksThereInLibrary: string;
  numberOfHistoryBooks: number;
  numberOfScienceBooks: number;
}

const getBooksPayload = (areBooksThereInLibrary: string):BooksList  => {
  if (areBooksThereInLibrary === 'No') {
    return {
      areBooksThereInLibrary: "No"
    }
  }
  return {
    areBooksThereInLibrary: 'Yes',
    numberOfHistoryBooks: 10,
    numberOfScienceBooks: 100
  }
};

getBooksPayload("No");
```

By default, I don't want to put the properties as optional like below:

```
interface BooksList {
      areBooksThereInLibrary: string;
      numberOfHistoryBooks?: number;
      numberOfScienceBooks?: number;
    }
```

Struggling to write a mapped typescript type where a couple of properties(`numberOfHistoryBooks`, `numberOfScienceBooks`) become optional based on property value.

Below is the typescript playground link for a complete environment of this issue and in here the error is highlighted in red:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GsDOAZYHMZAbwFgAoZZOKCDbHAFQAtoIBJEAgIyloCeALmREooAOYBuStRABXALY9oAeRgAJQmHRQBDXCIXLoMqsmMqo6gMoJgEEEgM4jSq2YC+lSgnQgiZAkIMBcABTgBABt0OAATZABeZAAKWnpMXFZ2Ll5+PRExSQBKIRcCQKSAPlJZZGAYVPSXbLpc4D5BJMTkgHIAOXRe4trzagB6ceQuZDAWQmQEOBwIABpkFnQAd1n0ZEU4LBQAA0s1TW1dfUycY5oQBNP3c7sHJwzGO-QABzBgfzgUQAdHVqHQwPIoCBRtRYTQ6C02G1uB18sJkAAiQYY5Cg5DecwEsEhSHQ8hjeEfLJIzgozoFZC9ACaEBwvVWeLO1guRCuLhEAEYAAwcilc2z2RzOG6CoVCuoEzxmSjBUI3CLRWJxFJY9AY4pAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define you `BooksList` this way:

```js
type BooksList = {
  areBooksThereInLibrary: 'No';
} | {
  areBooksThereInLibrary: 'Yes';
  numberOfHistoryBooks: number;
  numberOfScienceBooks: number;
}
```

If you prefer, you can define 2 named sub-interface and define `BooksList` as an union of the two. This could be helpful if you later want to do some type guards.